# Customize the back button of a navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I want to have two buttons on the left side of the navigation bar, one is the regular back button and the other one is a UIBarButtonItem. However I could only get it to replace the default back button. I've tried many code samples on the internet but couldn't get any to work. please help

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this.  It breaks the UI guidelines put forth by Apple.  [See the paragraph right before figure 6-6 of the iPhone HIG](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/SpecialViews/SpecialViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH10-SW5).

Comment: it's for an ipad app. if this is not recommended then what is? thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware it's not (currently) possible to have two `UIBarButtonItems` on either side of a `UINavigationBar`.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use the UIToolBar for multiple buttons on navigation  controller

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by-

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
UIImage *homeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE.png"];  
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:homeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(YOUR_ACTION)  
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 69, 26);  
UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:button1];
[button1 release];
button1 = nil;
```